# Здравствуйте! Вопрос: какого рода ГБОУ СОШ?

Tags: склонение

Склонение. Какого рода ГБОУ СОШ? (Государственное учреждение "Средняя общеобразовательная школа").
Определяется по слову Учреждение (средний род) или по слову *школа* (женский род)?
Например: ГБОУ СОШ №442 образовалось в 1956 году.
Или
ГБОУ СОШ №442 образовалась...

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

**Образовалось** (что?) **Государственное учреждение** (какое?) **"Средняя общеобразовательная школа".**
**"Средняя общеобразовательная школа"** здесь - просто название учреждения. С ним ничего согласовывать не нужно.
Изменение порядка слов (**"ГБОУ СОШ образовалось..."**) естественно никак не меняет ситуацию.